# How can I get the hostname of a socket?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

When I receive a certain event from a connected socket, I have to send a request with as parameter my hostname and port. I was hoping to be able to retrieve this information from the socket object. Unfortunately, there is little documentation on this and I can't seem to be able to find out if and how this is possible.

So, is it possible to do something like this in Socket.io:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log(socket.manager.server.hostname)
})'
```

(Or, alternatively: which thinking error am I making here in thinking that this should be possible in the first case?)

Comment: I have never used socket.io myself, but try to check what the context is (console.log(util.inspect(this)), maybe the information you are looking for is on the this object.

Comment: There is no way for `socket.io` to know how others can resolve the host it is on. Many times the host it is listening to is either `127.0.0.1` or `0.0.0.0` which is all it knows. If you know the hostname of your server will resolve properly you can use [`os.hostname()`](http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_hostname), or just place the host in a config file

Comment: @Chad Hmm, but with a normal request I can at least parse the URL of the request and deduce the hostname from that. Surely something like that should also be possible with Websockets?

Comment: @ExxKA Unfortunately the information I'm looking for was not present, but tips on how to find things out myself are always welcome, so thanks :)

Comment: My point was I don't think socket.io exposes that information

Comment: @Chad As in, it should be possible, but is not currently? Because if so, I could at least file a feature request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this:

```
console.log(socket.handshake.headers.host);
```

split port if necessary:

```
console.log(socket.handshake.headers.host.split(":").shift());
```

Comment: Awesome! Care to share how you found/knew this?

Comment: can this be 'faked'? Is it possible for the socket to send fake headers on connection and fake its hostname? I'm planning on using this an authentication option and I need to know if I should trust this

Comment: You can call console.log() from within your node script and just browse the object... e.g. console.log(socket).

All headers are "faked" in a way... it's just a string of text sent from the client (or proxy, if you're using one).

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer does not work anymore in 2022.

Today this information can be accessed like this:

```
const socket = io()

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Socket is connected with', this.socket.io.uri)
})
```