# Get domain name in node js

Tags: node.js, sockets

We are using node js socket in our project. We need to get the socket URL or the domain URL in our node JS server.js.
How can we get the domain url in nodeJS

Comment: Can you share with us the example url and what the expected output is? Or is this about getting the domain url of your NodeJS host?

Comment: @ionizer I am trying to connect to a single node socket port from different subdomains. I need to get the subdomain, which is trying to access the socket at server.js. At server.js, based on this subdomain, a database connection will be established. There are different databases for each subdomains.

Comment: I don't know if you're using socket.io, but have you checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15503308/how-can-i-get-the-hostname-of-a-socket